# Can we have a longer list of close nominated questions in the tools:close page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, 10k-tools, moderator-abilities

The moderator tools pages currently lists as many as 15 questions that have pending close votes and sorts them by the number of votes.

The very high activity on Stack Overflow means that there are always many more questions with pending close votes then can appear (it typically require 3 or 4 votes to even show up on the list). Consequently questions in low traffic tags, or those posted during off hours may get pushed far back in the front-page and newest views before they receive enough close votes to appear on the list.

I suppose it would require and unreasonably long list for *all* pending close votes, but can we have 20 or 25 instead of 15?

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27007/how-to-get-attention-required-to-close-old-posts

Comment: another related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49918/feature-request-mod-tools-chatroulette-next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now show `top 45` on the close and delete tabs, where before it was `top 15` or `top 30`

Answer (score 5):

I agree, I see many questions that just don't seem to earn enough close votes quickly enough, even though they probably should. Here's some from the last few days:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934437/tutorials-on-blogspot-template
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934281/computer-vision-research-related-blog
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926856/photo-gallery-for-wordpress
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926660/how-to-configurationerrorsexception-handling
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906370/how-can-i-run-atlassian-fisheye-as-a-windows-service

What I usually do these days is leave these kinds of questions open in tabs, and when the original close votes expire, ping a moderator to manually close/migrate.

I think a longer list of "pending close" questions would help bring some attention from 10k+ users to the ones with just one or two close votes.

Answer (score 4):

It might be useful to allow searching for such questions by a particular tag, so that users can focus on questions in topics in which they are most familiar.  (At least, this is what I was expecting such a page to look like. I'll find out in another month or two.)