# Make the "Most close votes" list longer

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, 10k-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a longer list of close nominated questions in the tools:close page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33459/can-we-have-a-longer-list-of-close-nominated-questions-in-the-toolsclose-page)

The list with questions with the most close votes in the tools pages for users with >10k reputation is currently limited to 15 entries. With the masses of questions asked each day, a question usually needs at least three close votes to show up on this list.

If it takes a few minutes for a question to collect it's first close vote, for example for being a duplicate, chances fall rapidly that it will actually be closed. If the question goes "out of the spot light" (which can happen very fast) without collecting three close votes it is no longer discoverable that this question should be closed as a duplicate.

The list of questions with "Most close votes" should be longer (lets say 50 entries), so that people can get a better overview of questions that might need to be closed.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33459/can-we-have-a-longer-list-of-close-nominated-questions-in-the-toolsclose-page

Answer (score 1):

Alternately a way given to sort them so you can look at the questions with only one close vote and edit/comment/vote on them as needed to speed up the process.

But the site is only going to get bigger.  Even if it's extended to 50 (still an arbitrary number) eventually it's going to overwhelm the list again.