# Is there a way to find questions that have close votes but are not closed yet?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

*I have recently passed 3000 reputation points on Super User*.

In my opinion there are not enough people to vote on closing on Super User so stuff that should be closed get two or three votes and then gets so old that no one notices them.

I would like to be able to view questions that someone voted to close during the last XX hours (where XX is something between 24 and 31.4152).

Is this possible?

Comment: +1 for "31.4152" (well that, and I agree with the idea - I had the same thing in the back of my mind ever since I got enough rep to close)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now it's only possible for moderators and users with more than 10K reputation.

Comment: For values of "moderator" equaling "10k user".

Comment: I didn't know that, in about 1300 rep I was going to find out

Comment: Even at that the list is shows only the top nominated questions and isn't very long: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33459/can-we-have-a-longer-list-of-close-nominated-questions-in-the-toolsclose-page

Comment: SO is designed so the richer get richer.. it stinks!

Comment: @user144819 - SO is designed so Jeff, Joel and other owners get paid in excchange for providing superior value to their customers (by offering great enough service to so many users that the ads on the site are worth it to advertizers). Any other real or percieved bias is just a side effect

Answer (score 4):

This [feature](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last2days) is part of the 10k reputation community moderation tools.

You might be able to make a compelling argument to lower the rep threshold, though, for this one function.

Comment: Actually, I think it has already been suggested somewhere.

Comment: I think the point is that this way new close-enable users get eased into the system because they *can't* find targets to make a lot of mistakes really quickly. Or maybe that is just my POV.

Comment: I agree; one should be closing questions for a while before being provided with a list of those that others think need to be closed. Otherwise, it's too easy for one badly-cast close vote to snowball.