# Tagging questions for closing

Tags: feature-request, tags, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to find questions that have close votes but are not closed yet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42707/is-there-a-way-to-find-questions-that-have-close-votes-but-are-not-closed-yet)
>   [On Home or Question page show close/reopen status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/on-home-or-question-page-show-close-reopen-status)

When questions get close votes, can we have them automatically tagged so that other users with the rep to close questions can see them? I find myself wondering if questions don't get closed simply because they don't have the visibility.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42707/is-there-a-way-to-find-questions-that-have-close-votes-but-are-not-closed-yet

Comment: see this link for one option: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/on-home-or-question-page-show-close-reopen-status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What questions don't get closed?
If you have examples, post them here please

I think they get closed quite successfully, and besides, 10k users and moderators can see a list with questions with close votes

Comment: Ah - didn't know about the 10k list, pretty much nullifies my suggestion. I think I've voted to close questions that weren't closed (obscure tags and graveyard timezones) but that could just be that I couldn't find the questions later... probably because they were closed :)

Comment: Ah, see I'd like to see that list.

Comment: A good incentive to reach 10k then!

Comment: When I first looked at the FAQ I thought it'd be impossible to hit 100. Then when I did I hit up a couple of downvotes and nearly lost it. I guess 10k isn't too hard.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this shouldn't be implemented using tags - they should be kept as a tool for categorising contents as much as possible.

I'd say it would be best implemented as a search term, a query string param or some other out of the way feature.

I'm also not sure that a list of questions with close votes should be available to all users... maybe I'm too pessimistic but I'd fear that would encourage less considered closing, with people regularly refreshing the close list, eager to close down posts.

Certainly a very handy moderator tool.

Comment: i tend to agree.  Jeff has stated several times that overloading the tag functionality isn't something he wants to do. (beyond the [faq] and [status-x] overloading in use here on meta, that is.)