# 10k "Most Delete Votes" List - Don't Show Questions I Can't Vote For

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, close-list

This is somewhat related to a [question here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33459/can-we-have-a-longer-list-of-close-nominated-questions-in-the-toolsclose-page) about whether the number of questions in the "Most Delete Votes" list in the 10k moderator tools should be increased. I looked for that question every way I could think of, to add this as an answer (if it wasn't closed), but couldn't find it.

It just struck me that when I'm looking for questions to vote to delete, it does me no good to see questions I've already voted to delete, or questions that have been migrated or locked. The list would often be long enough if such questions were omitted.

Comment: As a fellow deletionist, I approve this feature request. ;)

Comment: This one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33459/can-we-have-a-longer-list-of-close-nominated-questions-in-the-toolsclose-page

Comment: @fretje: yes. Thanks. _That's_ why I couldn't find it - it's about the **close** list!

Comment: I would also like to see questions less than three days old and answers not show up in the delete list unless I have 20k rep.

Comment: @Snowman frankly, I find these somewhat useful even though I have less than 20K. I review these and regularly find stuff worth flagging for mod attention (not surprising since these are posts considered harmful by trusted users)

Comment: @gnat then maybe have different views. Personally, I just want to burn through my delete votes as efficiently as possible, viewing only those items on which I can actually cast a vote.

Comment: @Snowman agree, different views could be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also would not mind seeing the vote count in another color (or something else obvious). I hit 10k today and found this to be a usability issue, especially with questions that have identical (rather, nearly identical) titles and both were closed.

Comment: Now that you are an employee, can something be done about this?

Comment: @durron597 I want to fix some of the moderator tooling first, because it's even more long overdue. That's an active initiative as of next week. The 10k tools were designed to facilitate more oversight, which at our current scale, is a function that they fundamentally don't provide very well. You need to be able to drill into those lists more conveniently at a much deeper breadth, and (optionally) filter out the stuff you can't act on, even if just seeing what's ultimately happened to it is interesting.

Answer (score 4):

At the very, very least, the lists should indicate which ones you've voted on. This would work best if the list was longer, of course.

I could see this implemented as sort of a toggle view where you could hide the ones you've voted for. This would keep the information *available* if you want to see it, which I think is the point of keeping them around currently.

Even with a list of 15 questions, it's tough to keep them all straight. As Ether said, you can look at whether the link is greyed out or not, but if you *don't* vote after viewing one of the questions, then that whole system breaks down.

This should apply to the delete list as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't mind seeing questions I've already voted for in the list (at least if I voted on the same machine, the link will be greyed out), but migrated questions are totally uneligible (for non-mods) so they should be in a different list altogether.  Perhaps there's already a "recently migrated" tab for mods, so these questions should go live there with that list.

While we're at it, a longer list of questions with delete votes would be welcome too.

Comment: @Ether: do you use the list to navigate to questions you've already voted on? May I ask for what purpose?

Comment: @John: I don't go to them again generally, but it would be nice to see which ones I've voted on so I don't go to them to vote on them again.