# Show users which posts they've already voted to close or delete on the mod tools page

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

The close and delete tabs of the [10k tools page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/) can get fairly cluttered, even here on MSO; I imagine it's ten times worse on SO. Could the page be modified to indicate which question(s) you've already voted to close or delete?

Comment: I imagine this is only going to be an indication on posts that are currently displayed? If the full history is shown, then closed questions can easily be cluttered by successful votes, while deleted questions will be cluttered by the non-expiring live votes.

Comment: Nice botch on your short comment. ♪

Comment: Thanks, @Grace! []()[]()[]()[]() '                         ' U+200U+200U+200

Comment: This was kind of mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44101/10k-most-delete-votes-list-dont-show-questions-i-cant-vote-for).

Comment: "I wanted to spend all of "2551 characters left" just to whine about this, but I'll stop here." :-)  That's when you would have found out the hard way that bounty reasons come out as one long paragraph (no formatting).

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, but the wall of text on the page would still be impressive. I should have thrown some Zalgo text in there too...

Comment: For those where I cannot retract my vote anyway (delete/undelete) or vote again (2nd time close/open), there's actually no excuse teasing me with it time and time again. Even for those where I can, seeing them just gets in the way, if interested I can just look at my votes. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44101

Answer (score 11):

Yes, please!

As one of a small number of users with vote-to-delete privs on some sites, I review the list of posts with delete votes fairly regularly.  The problem is that I can't tell, without clicking through and hovering over the delete link, whether a post is one I've already voted on, which is kind of a hassle.  Once I've voted there's nothing more I can do, so I'd like to know I can skip past those in the list.

This problem is exacerbated by two other factors: (1) for answers, the name of the answerer doesn't appear, just the title of the question (tonight I had multiple answers on the same question in that list), and (2) if I just click instead of spawning a new tab, then when I return to the list it's collapsed down to three again even if I had previously expanded it.

I don't think we want to remove posts from the list after voting (you still want a handle to the pending ones), but adding "(voted)" or some such after the post title would really help.  I've seen suggestions to change the link color; that might work, but let's not overload link color (which should mean visited/not visited), and anyway beware of accessibility concerns.  A text or graphical marker will work better for more users.

Alternatively, the lists could be subdivided into posts you've voted on and ones you haven't.  That seems like a more-major UI change, though.

I recognize that any solution to this problem will involve generating a different page for each user, while (probably) the current page is generated once for the site.  I don't know how much of a consideration that is.

Comment: WRT generating a different page per user (or let's say _filtering_): that's already done for all the review lists, so why not here?

Comment: @Mogsdad yeah, it might be fine; I don't know.  I know that there are some pages, or portions of pages, that are generated site-wide for performance considerations, and I don't know if this is one of them.  (Reviews are fed to you one at a time and you'll notice that the number up top doesn't adjust to your activity, BTW.)

Answer (score 6):

I want to add that, because the 10k tools page **also** shows questions that 20ks have voted to delete on, the list is mostly useless because it's dominated by questions that 10k users *cannot* delete.

These pages really need three things:

1. [10k "Most Delete Votes" List - Don't Show Questions I Can't Vote For](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44101/200235)
2. [Show users which posts they've already voted to close or delete on the mod tools page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/show-users-which-posts-theyve-already-voted-to-close-or-delete-on-the-mod-tools) (this question)
3. [Can we filter Flags in the 10K tools by tag too?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152968/can-we-filter-flags-in-the-10k-tools-by-tag-too)

There are so many requests for these things all over meta, and they keep being largely ignored in favor of "improved moderator tools" which never seem to come.

Please don't forget about us non-mods!