# Separate viewed but not-acted-upon mod flags from unviewed ones

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

On the moderator tools page, the flags tab has a list of all the current flagged posts and comments.

As a mod, I'll go through the list and act, but sometimes I also do NOT act.  This is often done on purpose, as I do not know what I should do, and so would like to leave it for other eyes to examine.

But those skipped flags are still mixed all up in the list of unviewed flags.  While they are grayed out, I've accidentally cleared a couple that I wanted to leave.

At least, would it be possible to sort flags by putting viewed ones at the end of the list?  Better, place them on a separate page (e.g., `1` `2` `Viewed` at the bottom of the list).

Comment: Plugs for related requests: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/show-users-which-posts-theyve-already-voted-to-close-or-delete-on-the-mod-tools and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44101/10k-most-delete-votes-list-dont-show-questions-i-cant-vote-for