# Show 10K users the delete votes of 20K users before deletion happens

Tags: feature-request, privileges, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, trusted-user

20K users can vote to delete recently closed questions and low scored answers. 10K users have limited delete vote powers, but should be able to view 20K delete votes. This would:

1. Serve as training for 20K vote delete powers
2. Provide additional oversight of things which might be deleted

Currently 10K users can only observe this "after the fact" which makes the opportunities to observe infrequent and doesn't make failed delete votes visible on answers at all.

Users who gain the close vote privilege have already had view close votes for a while as a "learning phase". This seems to work well. Doing similarly for 20K delete votes would make sense too I think.

Comment: 10k can view delete votes on questions, just not answers.

Comment: @Aarobot - you can't see it when browsing questions closed less than two days ago either. For example according to [this tool](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=today) there's a delete vote for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120030/interested-in-computational-physics-where-do-i-start), but no sign of it when I view the question itself. Adding it there would increase visibility with both of the benefits I suggested in this Q.

Comment: Wouldn't this just cause frustration for 10k users, by having them see something in the delete votes section that they can't do anything about?  The feature request [10k “Most Delete Votes” List - Don't Show Questions I Can't Vote For](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44101/10k-most-delete-votes-list-dont-show-questions-i-cant-vote-for), while from before the 20k additions, seems to indicate that 10k users wouldn't be happy seeing things they can't act on.

Comment: @brad - my view is/was that these are very different issues. The source of the frustration expressed in the post you linked is not that 10k users can't do anything with those posts so much as the fact that they block posts where they could take more useful action. This proposal wouldn't block visibility of anything ever.