# Don't show locked posts in the pending delete votes list

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, locked

[`/tools?tab=delete`](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete) shows a list of questions with pending delete votes. Currently, the list contains locked questions that happened to pick up a delete vote (or two) before they were locked. Regular users can't vote to delete those questions, and - assuming the lock is correct - there's little reason for moderators to step in.

Therefore, locked questions only add noise to an already hard to navigate list. Let's remove them from it.

Comment: +1 Don't have access to the mod-tools, but sounds reasonable.

Comment: Related: [10k “Most Delete Votes” List - Don't Show Questions I Can't Vote For](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44101/162704) (it mentions locked posts, so it might be considered a duplicate)

Comment: I also just found a merge stub in the list... Noise, noise, noise...