# Feature-request: mod tools: Chatroulette 'Next'

Tags: feature-request, moderator-abilities

I go to the mod tools. I see a list of questions with some close votes. Some of them I don't agree with. So, I'd like to see the next 15. Oops. No way to do that. The ones I choose not to vote for prevent me from seeing others that I might want to vote for. At the moment, there are a lot of questions with some close votes, so you can't see them all.

I wish that I could click on one of these and say 'don't show me this again', thus leaving room in the list for more.

I think that there's another weird side effect of the current situation: Things get closed and deleted perhaps undeservedly.

This is best illustrated on the delete tab. At any given moment, the delete tab is populated by a load of possible deletions. Many were closed as duplicates. Some people around here think that we don't delete duplicates. Some people are wrong. Once nominated by one delete vote, my experience is that they **always** get deleted. Why? Well, if for no other reason, to clear them off the top of the list.

I suspect a similar process on the close list. Once a thing has some close votes, it just sits out there with a "kickme" sign. 10Ks and mods are then tempted to vote it off the island just to get it out of the way. If we could click on 'I don't want to close this, don't show it to me any longer,' that wouldn't be operative.

And, at the moment, a question with **no** pending close votes is at the top of the list, because it's been through two complete cycles. I suppose I should flag it.

Comment: I wish there were a "don't show me this again" on the Unanswered page.

Comment: You really want to start stealing ideas from chatroulette? That can only lead to one thing...

Comment: @Jon B John Skeet naked?

Comment: I *do* vote to delete duplciates, provided that 1) They don't have any answers or they have few and they are patently duplicates of or less helpful that ones existing on the earlier incarnation **and** 2) the title does not seem to offer different searchability. And because I will vote to delete duplicates, and often leave a comment when I think that we *shouldn't* delete a particular duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

[How about we just make the list longer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33459/can-we-have-a-longer-list-of-close-nominated-questions-in-the-toolsclose-page)

Comment: I'd certainly settle for that as a first step. Let me go upvote.