# Downvoting does not decrease rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvotes on questions be “free”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)

I went on a downvote spree today (because of [low quality homework-style questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108521/168373)). I have not lost any rep during my spree. Shouldn't I have lost rep? Just wanted to point this out to the powers that be so I also play by the rules..

Answer (score 4):

Downvoting a question does not impose a rep penalty.

Downvoting an answer will cost you 1 rep.

Comment: where is that written?