# Require activity within a question's topic in order to cast close votes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

In certain cases, the questions are getting closed by folks who have never answered any question in a certain topic. For example, I had asked this question on Stack Overflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671605/key-strokes-mac. The person who has closed this has not answered a single question on Cocoa. This leads me to believe that he has no idea of what I am asking. And he has closed the question.

Can anything like this be done? A question has certain tags associated with it. And considering the fact that closing the question is important, can we set it up such that the person who closes a question should have asked/answered a question which has that tag? Otherwise, we will have C# developers closing Objective-C questions.

Comment: Your question really seems like a configuration question. You make no mention of code in it. I can *imagine* how it might be a coding question, but I have to work to do so.

Comment: ok got it, added the code to the question.

Comment: (somewhat) related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103207/give-more-weight-to-close-as-duplicate-votes-from-gold-silver-tag-badge-carriers

Comment: Oh yes, this is a very very good idea, I am really fed up with seeing the most vigorous reviewers closing questions (in particular on Physics SE) about topics they have no clue about and therefore NOT the right to judge their merits ... That would be such a great improvement, but as expected the MSO crowd strongly resits any such improvements.

Answer (score 10):

Your question arguably should not have been closed. But your proposed solution doesn't help at all. I am, primarily, a software developer, and secondarily a .NET and database developer. I dabble in many different areas, as many devs do. I can look at *most* other language questions ([R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) throws me) and see whether it should continue or go away. Most competent developers can do the same.

Comment: I'm curious, what is it about R that throws you? I ask because R is pretty much all I know. I have a very rudimentary understanding of the basics in some areas (SQL, Javascript, PHP, Python), but I'd never try to answer questions there. But, like you, I find that there's plenty of  editing/closing I feel comfortable doing on other tags, but I try to stick to fairly obvious stuff.

Comment: @joran, I mean I can't really tell whether an R question is off-topic or not, so I don't try. Many of them read to me like the OP is asking how to use graphing or plotting software. Once I read the answers, I know I've got it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I **am** a Mac developer and I had a really hard time following your question. Without code, the original version could easily be taken as you asking for how to configure the OS, unless you really dug into it.

I've edited your question to try and clarify what you want to do (and given it a much more descriptive title than just "Key strokes Mac"), but even there I couldn't figure out what you were asking at parts.  For example, the sentence

> I have tried detecting the cmd + shift + eject key combination and
>   tried adding the same code.

doesn't really make any sense. What code are you talking about here? A clearer question would have avoided this problem to begin with.

As kiamlaluno points out, this was closed by Robert Harvey, a moderator, so no scheme to restrict close votes by area of activity would have worked here. Moderators by definition have almost unlimited power, because they need to handle things that normal users cannot. Odds are, someone who frequents the [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) tag flagged your question as being off-topic, and Robert responded to that flag. Even though he's not a Mac or iOS developer, I can say that he's done a great job in the related tags there, from my perspective as someone familiar with these topics.

Restricting close votes only to areas that you participate over a certain threshold in would lead to more low-quality content working its way into the system. It's generally pretty easy to recognize garbage questions or completely off-topic material, no matter your area of expertise. I cast a lot of close votes in the [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) tag, for example, as do others, due to the flood of terrible material coming in there lately, but I have answered nothing in that area.

Answer (score 2):

Voting to close a question is not related to having answered to any question using any of the tags used by that question. If a question is not constructive (or a duplicate of another question), it is still a not constructive (or a duplicate) question even if I have never answered to questions about Objective-C.

In the specific case, who closed the question is a moderator; if we are going to have a moderator for each of the tags used on Stack Overflow, the number of moderators would be a way higher than it is now.

In any case, if the question has been wrongly closed, five users (or another moderator) can re-open it. Closing a question is not forever; it could be forever, if the question is not acceptable for the site where it has been asked.
Limiting who can vote to close a question doesn't make sense, considering that questions can be voted to be re-opened.